Saas vs brochure style
I'm just in the process of buying a website and as I'm new to this and hearing conflicting messages I wanted to see what people thought here.
Essentially I want to make a tutoring website where the functionality will be as follows:

Bespoke design
Chat box
Student login
Tutor login
Notes (free and behind a subscription . Include videos..articles..podcasts)
Contact form
Blog posts

I want the students to log in to view paid content.
I want the tutors to log in to edit their profiles.
I was told that for a first roll out its a bad idea to start with an Saas and I should just focus on traffic with a simple (potentially one page) brochure website. But the developer was very poor at explaining why
I feel like this looks overly simplistic and so would seem unprofessional. I also don't see how this would negatively affect my site in any way (beyond less money for other purposes due to higher price point )
Is there any negative reasons you can think of that would mean I shouldn't go with all the functionality above and instead go for the most simple possible design you can imagine ?

(This is off topic here as its about a single site, and you are clearly not a webmaster) I think you are being BS'd - SaaS does not come into play here - you are probably wanting to look at an LMS (Learning Management System).    It is unclear what you are buying, but getting a Wordpress site with an LMS plugin will take you a lot further then a brochure site and needs not cost a huge amount of money.   It will handle everything in your list, but it may not scale massively - still it would be more then enough to see if you have a viable business and if you need something $$$ and bespoke.

You need a minimum viable product to launch.  Nothing more.
Users tend to direct requirements, and having launch phases is a good idea to prevent you wasting money on features that never get used.
A one page seems very minimal first stage, admittedly, but it might allow you to make sure there's an audience in the first place.  Getting some people signing up for the launch announcement can only be a good thing for launch day, and means you also have some people available for pre-launch feedback.
The full build of such a project could take some time, so there's no harm doing a bit of market research alongside it.
